# Wordpress as CakePHP plugin

Tags: wordpress, cakephp, plugins

I have a website running CakePHP 1.3. This website also has several plugins that act as different sections of the website, whose access is controlled by a global Auth component.

I would like to know if it would be possible to install Wordpress as one of this plugins. I would most likely don't need any of the user comments features that Wordpress has.

I believe that maybe I would be able to put in the the "webroot" folder of a plugin, but then its content would be freely accessible right?

Answer (score 1):

Not as a plugin but you can run both Cake and Wordpress from the server root without them messing with each other:

```
/
    /app
    /cake
    /wordpress_installation
```

There are ways of sharing sessions between Cake and Wordpress too.

Comment: thanks for your reply! Do you kow where to find an example of "sharing sessions"? I would need to restric the access to the blog to users who have already logged in using the global Auth component

Answer (score 0):

i would go like this

```
/app/webroot
/app/webroot/wordpress
```

this way it is cleaner because the app itself shoulnt be available to the outside.
always use webroot as "root" for your vhosts path

but other than that it will work out of the box

Comment: but if I put it there, how can I limit the access to only logged in users? Everyone has access to the webroot folder right?